# Different types of merging in dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes with shapes:

```
df1.shape = (30649, 18)
df2.shape = (5730, 4)
```

I have two ways of merging:

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=["A", "B", "I],
          right_on=["A", "B", "P"]) 

new_df_v1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', left_on=["A", "B", "I"],
                     right_on=["A", "B", "P"])
```

The column names are the same, except for the 'I' and 'P', however the values in each column  are the same *type.*

When I inspect the output of the shapes, I get:

```
print(f"{df1.shape}, {df2.shape}, {new_df.shape}, {new_df_v1.shape}")
(30649, 18), (5730, 4), (5468, 20), (5732, 20)
```

I was expecting the *new_df* and *new_df_v1* shapes to be the same, but they differ. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, left_on=["A", "B", "I], right_on=["A", "B", "P"])` here `how` is `inner`, in latter `how` is `right`, so different output.

Comment: in the first case you missed `how='right'`?

Comment: @Ch3steR (and political scientist): thanks, I though it was something overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `new_df_v1`, the `how='right'` argument is telling the merging function to `use only keys from right frame, similar to a SQL right outer join; preserve key order.` Whereas when you do `df.merge`, the default behavior is to join by the union of the keys: `* inner: use intersection of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL inner join; preserve the order of the left keys.`

Comment: @ Landmaster: I changed it, yes you're right and now the shapes are the same. Not originally asked, but is one method of merging (df1.merge or pd.merge) favoured over the other?

Comment: Merge, join, and concat are a helluva topic - you can read about it in the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html). I really don't think there's a 'better way,' but I havent really taken the time to profile their run times.

Comment: Yes I anticipate too there is a difference between these 3 constructors...I was just trying to figure why one can merge using two different ways (using just the 'merge' constructor).